# Accessing GPS / location data using Cloudpebble and PebbleJs

Tags: gps, location, pebble-watch, cloudpebble, pebble-js

Trying to show my current GPS location on my pebble by writing a simple script (see code below).

It all works just fine, but I cannot access the GPS-values.

The code is built on [pebbles own geolocation example](http://developer.getpebble.com/guides/js-apps/js-other/#geolocation).

My problem is that I can only get the GPS data within the function **locationSuccess()** .

How do I access the GPS data (i.e. the values of **myLat** and **myLong**) outside that function? I want to put the GPS data into this line:

```
text : 'GPS:\n',
```

I am using CloudPebble and Pebble.js

**The code:**

```
var UI = require('ui');
var Vector2 = require('vector2');

var locationOptions = {
  enableHighAccuracy: true, 
  maximumAge: 10000, 
  timeout: 10000
};


// Get the location
function locationSuccess(pos) {
    console.log('\n****** START ******\nhere I am:\nlat= ' + pos.coords.latitude + ' lon= ' + pos.coords.longitude + '\n'); // Just to se that it works fine
    var myLat = pos.coords.latitude;
    var myLong = pos.coords.longitude;
    console.log('My location\n' + myLat + ' and ' + myLong + '\n****** THE END  02 ******\n'); // This does also work fine
}   
function locationError(err) {
  console.log('location error (' + err.code + '): ' + err.message);
}

// Make an asynchronous request
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(locationSuccess, locationError, locationOptions);


// Create a text object 
var infotext = new UI.Text(
{
  position: new Vector2(0, 0),
  size: new Vector2(144, 168),
    text : 'GPS:\n',
  font: 'Gothic 28',
  color: 'white',
  textAlign: 'center'   
});

// Create and show the location (vars x and y are empty - why?)
var infowindow = new UI.Window();
infowindow.add(infotext);
infowindow.show();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I can't add a comment to your post I will edit my first answer.  Sorry for the mistakes in my first answer, I was not too familiar with the geolocation function.

You are not receiving any response at **the end 02** because the function `locationSuccess()` has not ran yet, so no values have been assigned to `myLat` and `myLong`.

The reason that you are not receiving a response at **the end 03** is because the function `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` works asynchronously. It hasn't finished running when your next `console.log` executes so the values of your variables still haven't been set.

What I would suggest is to wrap your code that uses the geolocation into your `locationSuccess` function, since this success function is the intended area for that type of code anyhow.

#### Changes I Made:

By moving your success code into the success function, you no longer have to initialize the latitude and longitude variables, so I removed those from the code below.  I also modified your original GPS window text `infotext` to display: "Loading GPS Data...".  That way `infowindow` loads immediately, and shows a loading screen while `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` runs in the background.

Once the current position is found it will run the success function. I added a line to the end of this function to update the text in the GPS window to display the latitude and longitude. I also added a similar line to the error function to let the user know if something went wrong. You shouldn't need to call `infowindow.add(infotext);` or `infowindow.show();` again for the text to update on the screen. I also moved `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` below the creation of the info window/text, so that the success/error functions cannot try to update the text before the text UI was created.

#### Updated Code:

```
var UI = require('ui');
var Vector2 = require('vector2');

var locationOptions = {
  enableHighAccuracy: true, 
  maximumAge: 10000, 
  timeout: 10000
};

// Get the location
function locationSuccess(pos) {
    console.log('\n****** START ******\nhere I am:\nlat= ' +     pos.coords.latitude + ' lon= ' + pos.coords.longitude + '\n'); // Just to se     that it works fine
    var myLat = pos.coords.latitude;
    var myLong = pos.coords.longitude;
    console.log('My location\n' + myLat + ' and ' + myLong + '\n****** THE END  01 ******\n'); // This does work fine
    //modify the text within infotext to show GPS data
    infotext.text('GPS:\n' + myLat + '\n' + myLong);
}   
function locationError(err) {
  console.log('location error (' + err.code + '): ' + err.message);
    //modify the text within infotext to alert user of error
    infotext.text('Error Loading GPS Data!');
}

console.log('My location\n' + myLat + ' and ' + myLong + '\n****** THE END      02 ******\n'); 

// Create a text object 
var infotext = new UI.Text(
{
  position: new Vector2(0, 0),
  size: new Vector2(144, 168),
  text : 'Retrieving GPS Data...',  
  font: 'Gothic 28',
  color: 'white',
  textAlign: 'center'   
});

// Create and show the location (vars x and y are empty - why?)
var infowindow = new UI.Window();
infowindow.add(infotext);
infowindow.show();

// Make an asynchronous request
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(locationSuccess, locationError,locationOptions);

console.log('My location\n' + myLat + ' and ' + myLong + '\n****** THE END  03 ******\n');
```

/edit

### Original Answer:

The variables `myLat` and `myLong` are local variables in the function `locationSuccess`.  To fix this issue you must change the *scope* in which `myLat` and `myLong` are defined.

In the below example, I defined the variables *globally* so that all scripts and functions can reference them.

```
var UI = require('ui');
var Vector2 = require('vector2');

//define variables globally
var myLat;
var myLong;

var locationOptions = {
  enableHighAccuracy: true, 
  maximumAge: 10000, 
  timeout: 10000
};


// Get the location
function locationSuccess(pos) {
    console.log('\n****** START ******\nhere I am:\nlat= ' + pos.coords.latitude + ' lon= ' + pos.coords.longitude + '\n'); // Just to se that it works fine
    //assign value to globally scoped variables
    myLat = pos.coords.latitude;
    myLong = pos.coords.longitude;
    console.log('My location\n' + myLat + ' and ' + myLong + '\n****** THE END  02 ******\n'); // This does also work fine
}   
function locationError(err) {
  console.log('location error (' + err.code + '): ' + err.message);
}

// Make an asynchronous request
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(locationSuccess, locationError, locationOptions);


// Create a text object 
var infotext = new UI.Text(
{
  position: new Vector2(0, 0),
  size: new Vector2(144, 168),
    text : 'GPS:\n',
  font: 'Gothic 28',
  color: 'white',
  textAlign: 'center'   
});

// Create and show the location (vars x and y are empty - why?)
var infowindow = new UI.Window();
infowindow.add(infotext);
infowindow.show();
```

For further information on variable scope, [this](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp) is a good reference.